# How do I turn my INT (id) into a String in my return from MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to my a very simple webapplication, webshop, for cupcakes.

From the webApp you can choose a cupcake form the dropdown with three attributes
(top, bottom, quantity). These are stored in an ArrayList on my sessionScope but all in numbers e.g. Chokolate as 1 and Vanilla as 2. I want to use these topId numbers to ask my DB (MySQL) for what is in 1 and then have it return Chokolate.

I think I am almost there with my code, but can't get it to return my String, as my topId is an Int.

```
    public static Top getTopById(int topId) {
        readFromArrayPutInSQL();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO cupcaketopping (toppingType, toppingPrice) VALUES (?, ?)";

        try {
            ConnectionPool connectionPool = new ConnectionPool();
            String query = "SELECT toppingType FROM cupcaketopping";
            Statement statement = connectionPool.getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            rs.getString(topId);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return topId; //Here is the problem - I GUESS?
    }
```

Code after changes due to input in comments, seem to be working!

```
public static Top getTopById(int topId) {
        readFromArrayPutInSQL();

        String query = "SELECT toppingType FROM cupcaketopping WHERE toppingID = "+topId+"";

        try {
            ConnectionPool connectionPool = new ConnectionPool();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connectionPool.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
            rs.next();
            return new Top(rs.getString(1));

            //connectionPool.close(); //NOTE! Won't run, IntelliJ is asking me to delete! 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. You're selecting all rows from the `cupcaketopping` table, regardless of the `topId`. You should probably be using a `PreparedStatement`, and then use `topId` as part of your query.
2. You never call `ResultSet#next()`. The result set always starts "before" the first row. You have to call `next()` for each row in the result set (it returns `true` if there is a row to read).
3. The `ResultSet#getString(int)` method gets the `String` value of the column at the given index of the result. You only select one column, so the argument should probably be `1` (not `topId`).
4. You never close the `Statement` when done with it.

   - Depending on how your connection pool class works, you might actually need to close the `Connection` instead.
5. You never try to use the `String` returned by `rs.getString(topId)`.
6. You never try to convert the query result to a `Top` instance.
7. Given it's possible the query will return no result, you might want to consider making the return type `Optional<Top>`.
8. The `sql` string seems to have no purpose.

Your code should look more like this:

```java
public Optional<Top> getTopById(int topId) {
    Connection conn = ...;

    String query = "SELECT toppingType FROM cupcaketopping WHERE id = ?";
    // closes the statement via try-with-resources
    try (PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        stat.setInt(1, topId);

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
        // assume unique result (as it's assumed the ID is the primary key)
        if (rs.next()) {
            // assumes 'Top' has a constructor that takes a 'String'
            return Optional.of(new Top(rs.getString(1)));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Your actual implementation may vary, depending on how the rest of your code is designed.

Comment: Your answer made a lot of sense, ofc I forgot to be specific with the topID an use it.

I've tried to change my code with your input, but not made it 100% like yours, mostly because I need to understand what I'm doing.